# node.js application running on a port should have no port visible in the URL bar

Tags: node.js, apache, port, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have 5 domains pointing to the same machine, let's say these domains are:

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
example5.com
```

- My server has a virtual host file managed by apache, which controls these 5 domains.
- I have a node.js app running on port 3000.

If I connect to any of the 5 domains, and type :3000 at the end, I can see the node.js app splash screen.

For example, if I connect to `example1.com:3000` it serves me the same page (the node.js app) that can be reached by connecting to `example2.com:3000` and `example3.com:3000`, etc. I understand why this is happening.

However, I am trying to edit my configuration such that the following criteria are met:

- Users can only connect to the node app when they type in `example5.com`, and not any of the other domains.
- Users do not have to type in the port number, `example5.com:3000`, when trying to reach the node app.

I have searched and found some information which leads me to believe this is normally achieved by setting up a reverse proxy, but most examples I find are using nginx or node. It would be nice to figure out a reverse proxy solution with apache so I don't have to re-write all my virtual host logic with node or nginx.

Comment: Several articles worth reading [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+as+reverse+proxy+for+node.js&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS515US515&oq=apache+as+reverse+proxy+for+node.js&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.9479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Well - basically your question is indeed 'how do I setup apache as reverse proxy for node.js' - because this is the only option that makes sense here.

Asking google for that brought this result: http://garr.me/blog/running-node-js-and-apache-together-using-mod_proxy/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a reverse proxy. An easy way to do this is to use nginx. Install and start nginx and in your config file put the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example1.com;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

And then run your node server on port 3000.